# Creating HTML pages from POJO data

Tags: java, html

If the task is to produce HTML document from some POJO bean, what is the simplest approach one can follow to get is done? Document is no more complicated then series of tables with headers and some merged elements here and there.

Solution we have today works, but is (**concern**) very tightly coupled with the code engine that produces the bean and I'd like to either rewrite it or use an existing solution.

**(concern)** The main goal is too not worry about tags, html values, table structure etc and to keep these things as much out of .java as possible.

If at all possible, do provide examples. Thank you.

Comment: I'd personally use JAXB to serialize to XML, then transform to XHTML with XSLT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a templating engine. Look into [`Velocity`](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [`Freemarker`](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

**EDIT**

I know you said "main goal is too not worry about tags, html values, [etc.]," but I think a template-based approach is cleaner and easier to maintain than a code-based solution.

Comment: I am going with Velocity. It does what I need cleanly and easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is apache tiles (template engine).